# Exclude outliers while trying to get the average

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, math

I'm using cakephp for a website that allows users to log their substance use.

What I want to do is get the average dose of a specific substance. I've done this with setting a virtualfield

```
    $this->RecordDrugUnit->virtualFields['sum'] ='AVG(RecordDrugUnit.dose)';
```

The problem though is, if a user messed up and has a messed up value like 100000 grams of alcohol taken, then this will screw up the average. So I want to exclude to outliers, or somehow figure out a better way to gather the average.

Anyone have any input on this?

Comment: This article might help you: http://www.ryanbyrd.net/techramble/2012/01/18/mysql-strip-outliers-for-average-and-standard-deviation/

Comment: Do you know what the normal values should be?  If you do, then you simply structure your query to only return results within a normal range.  If you don't, then how do you know it wasn't supposed to be that value?  Also, checking the values server and/or client side before submitting them could eliminate the need to modify the query.  I think it would be best if you knew what valid values actually were and checked for them before inserting.

Comment: You could also use MODE to figure out which dose is used the most or MEDIAN to get the dose that is not the average but the one that falls in the middle.  I think mode might be the best bet though.

Comment: Using mode is a bad way to do it - outliers ought to be determined by standard deviation (e.g. STDDEV(RecordDrugUnit.dose) ) like scrowler's comment. Typically outliers are determined by being 3 standard deviations off, but you can always fiddle with that a bit if you find it's accidentally removing too much (or not enough.)

Comment: user3071296, this would work if I only needed the data for one substance. So I can set it to get values between 1mg and 10mg. But I have over 130 drugs, and their valid values range widely. Some from .001 mg, some are at 20 ounces. So that method would only work if I made exceptions for every single drug and that's not really efficient

Comment: Average is *one* measure of central tendency. It's not necessarily the best one. Taking the median would reduce the effect of outliers without your having to identify the reason for the outlier. The average of {4,7,2,2,9,8,3} is 5. The median is 4. The average of {4,7,2,2,9,8,3,100000} is 12504.38. The median is 5.5.

Comment: Mike, that's a good point. I'm going to try that and see what the results are like. What would you say about using the Median method vs Standard Deviation?

Comment: Though you are using CakePHP it has no bearing at all on the question. I suggest editing your question to only be about the problem (sql) showing some test data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by excluding variables which are too far from the standard deviation, where 3 * standard deviation from the average is commonly considered an 'outlier'. If you only want to exclude the *very* far off the average, you can just increase the amount that stddev is multiplied by. Here's a very simplified, unoptimized approach you can use as a starting point for whatever virtualField you choose to use:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
| 1000 |
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test where (ABS(test.a - (select avg(a) from test)) < 3*(select stddev(a) from test));
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I believe if a virtualfield contains a select, that select is simply run, so you can use this directly. My quick, untested attempt at a virtualfield:

```
$this->RecordDrugUnit->virtualFields['sum'] = 'select AVG(rdu.dose) from RecordDrugUnit rdu where (ABS(rdu.dose - (select avg(dose) from rdu)) < 3*(select stddev(dose) from rdu))';
```

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful in helping me understand what I need to do. Now I just need to figure out how to do this using cakephp. I tried         $this->RecordDrugUnit->virtualFields['sum'] ='ABS(RecordDrugUnit.dose - AVG(RecordDrugUnit.dose)) < 3*STDDEV(RecordDrugUnit.dose)';
, But I think i'm missing something

Comment: Just updated with my best-guess as to what to make your virtualfield. If I'm off by a parenthesis or something please edit the answer so it can be used by others.

Comment: For some reason, this returns the same value no matter which drug/array it gets.

Comment: You can try lowering the coefficient on the stddev down until it filters out what you want. 3 stddevs is a considerable deviation from the mean. It might be easier to work out in the mysql command line and see what you're getting. Check what the avg(dose) and stddev(dose) are, then select all doses and see if it's going to exclude those you want excluded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [trimmed mean](http://www.statistics.com/glossary&term_id=866) function for that. If you're interested I can add the procedure later today.

```
-- Add trimmed mean user defined function

-- ------------------------------ START FUNCTION --------------------------------
drop function if exists trimmed_mean;

delimiter //

create function trimmed_mean(
    -- data: comma separated list of numeric values, left-to-right sorted from low to high
    -- (you can use GROUP_CONCAT(x ORDER BY x) to let MySQL generate suchs lists for you
    data   text
    -- p: the percentage of the data points to trim.
,   p      tinyint
)
returns double
begin
    -- n: number of observations
    declare n int default 1 + length(data) - length(replace(data, ',', ''));
    -- m: number of observations to remove on both ends of the data set
    declare m int default n * p / 2 / 100;
    -- t: trimmed dataset
    declare t text default substring_index(substring_index(data, ',', n-m), ',', -(n-m-m));
    -- current character (for parsing numbers out of the dataset)
    declare c varchar(1);
    -- x: integer part of the data point, y: decimal part of the data point
    declare x, y varchar(32);
    -- z: number of decimals
    declare z int unsigned default 0;
    -- number of characters in the (trimmed) data set
    declare l int unsigned default length(t);
    -- i: current position in the data set, j: marks start of data point
    declare i, j int unsigned default 1;
    -- the sum of the integer parts of the data points
    declare v int default 0;
    -- d: the sum of the decimal parts of the data parts (as scaled integer), s: scaling factor
    declare d, s int unsigned default 0;
    repeat
        -- get the current character from the trimmed data set
        set c = substring(t, i, 1);
        -- check if current position is a data point separator (',') or end of data terminator ('')
        if substring(t, i, 1) in (',', '') then
            -- parse out a data point (from j up to i) into x; advance j and look for a decimal separator ('.')
            set x = substring(t, j, i - j),
                j = i + 1,
                d = instr(x, '.')
            ;
            -- if we have no decimals, then parse data point as integer and update our sum v with it.
            if d = 0 then
                set v = v + cast(x as signed);
            else
            -- we have decimals. Parse up to the decimal separator ('.') as integer and update our sum v.
            -- parse out the part after the decimal separator into y. Update the total number of decimals to keep track of in z
            -- Finally, pad our decimal parts sum with the number of decimals and prepend a 1 to not lose leading zeroes
                set v = v + cast(substring_index(x, '.', 1) as signed)
                ,   y = substring_index(x, '.', -1)
                ,   z = greatest(z, length(y))
                ,   d = cast(rpad(cast(d as char), '0', z + 1) as unsigned) + cast(rpad(concat('1', y), '0', z + 1) as unsigned)
                ;
            end if;
        end if;
        -- advance position to look at next character in the dataset.
        set i = i + 1;
    -- stop scanning when we ran trhough the dataset.
    until c = '' end repeat;
    -- compute the scaling factor s (1 followed by number of zeroes equal to max number of decimals)
    -- update n to the number of original observations minus the specified percentage.
    set s = cast(rpad('1', '0', z + 1) as unsigned)
    ,   n = (n - 2 * m)
    ;
    -- add sum of integer parts to the (downscaled) sum of decimal parts, and divide to get the mean.
    return (v + case d when 0 then 0 else (d - n * s) / s end) / n;
end
//

delimiter ;
-- ------------------------------- END FUNCTION ---------------------------------
```

Comment: I've never dealt with anything like that, so it's going to take me a long time to figure out what's going on and how to use this with cakephp, but thanks for the post, I'll look into it.